# Density Heat Map on Google Map using R

Tags: r, google-maps

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
  longitude   latitude    Magnitude
1 -77.08597 38.7347905  4.742112594
2 -77.08597 38.8081915  4.742112594
3 -77.08597 38.8815925  5.278542493
4 -77.08597 38.9549935 12.270006486
5 -77.08597 39.0283945  4.742112594
6 -77.08597 39.1017955  4.742112594
```

Is there any way to take these coordinates and magnitude and plot a density map using Google Maps?

I have tried using the `raster` and `spatstat` packages to create a map using the coordinates and plotting intensity on it. But I haven't found any solution to plot it on Google Maps.

Comment: Have a look at https://sites.google.com/site/davidkahle/ggmap

Comment: ggmap and stat_density2d are the way to go. But the fact that your longitudes are all identical is going to cause some trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ggmap pacakge of R.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

map = get_map(location = c(-77.08597,38.7),source="google",maptype="roadmap",zoom=12)
ggmap(map)+geom_point(data = dat2,aes(x=longitude,y=latitude,size=Magnitude))
```

You can either scale the the Magnitude vector or increase the zoom

Answer (score 1):

I have a Google Maps widget in my [`googleway`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) package that uses the Google Maps API, including their `heatLayer`.

To use their API you also need an API key.

```
library(googleway)

## genreate some random data
set.seed(20160907)
df <- data.frame(longitude = runif(10000, min = -78, max = -74),
                                 latitude = runif(10000, min = 37, max = 40),
                                 Magnitude = rexp(10000, 1))

##key <- 'your_api_key'

google_map(data = df, key = key) %>%
    add_heatmap(weight = "Magnitude", option_radius = 0.1)
```

[image]